# Unable to fix "Type of this values must be known...." when using a iterator

Tags: rust

I'm using Hyper on the server side:

```
    //"req" is hyper::server::Request
    match req.headers().iter().collect().filter(|x| x.name() == "field123").first() {
      Some(...) => ...........
    }
```

Error:

```
    error[E0619]: the type of this value must be known in this context
   --> src/main.rs:123:31
    |
123 |                         match req.headers().iter().collect().filter(|x| x.name() == "field123").first() {
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What "value" exactly? Why does the error occur?

How to fix it?

Comment: Why do you need `collect` in the first place?  You're taking a collection, turning it into an iterator, then immediately turning it back into a collection, followed by trying to invoke an iterator method (which aren't on collections).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot deduce what sort of collection you want.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect

> Because collect() is so general, it can cause problems with type inference. As such, collect() is one of the few times you'll see the syntax affectionately known as the 'turbofish': ::<>. This helps the inference algorithm understand specifically which collection you're trying to collect into.

Consider:

```
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let output = input.iter().map(|&x| x).collect();
println!("{:?}", output);

3 | let output = input.iter().map(|&x| x).collect();
  |     ^^^^^^
  |     |
  |     cannot infer type for `_`
  |     consider giving `output` a type
```

vs:

```
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let output = input.iter().map(|&x| x).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
println!("{:?}", output);

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You probably want something along these lines, although I'm not sure what, based on your tiny snippet:

```
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let output = input.iter().filter(|&x| *x > 5).nth(0);
println!("{:?}", output);
```

Otherwise, explicitly use `collect::<...>` to resolve the output type.

Comment: `nth(0)` doesn't help